# Groovy: JLine does not wait for input Gradle

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, system.in, jline3

OS: Windows 10, mainly using Cygwin.

I put together a DummyMain.groovy file like so:

```
@Grab(group='org.jline', module='jline', version='3.7.0')
class DummyMain {

static void main( args ) {
    new DummyMain().go()
}

def go() {
    def terminal = org.jline.terminal.TerminalBuilder.builder().jna( true ).system( true ).build()
    terminal.enterRawMode()
    def reader = terminal.reader()
    int readInt = -1
    while( readInt != 13 ) {
        readInt = reader.read()
        println "read |$readInt| class ${readInt.class.simpleName}"
        println "reader class ${reader.class.simpleName}"
    }
    reader.close()
    terminal.close()
}
```

}

When I run this by going `groovy DummyMain` in its own directory this works as expected and fills me with joy: the `reader.read()` line pauses for the next character, and then processes it (i.e. before the user presses Enter to end the line).

But when I comment out the `@Grab` and put this line in `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'org.jline:jline:3.7.0'
```

and try to run this file using the simplest possible `build.gradle` it fails: the `while` loops spins on endlessly without waiting for user input, i.e. endlessly printing "read |-1|...".

This failure to wait happens if I use a Cygwin console or a Windows CMD console to go `gradle run`.

From the other print line I can tell that the reader here is class `NonBlockingInputStreamReader` in all 3 cases (i.e. Gradle via Cygwin, Gradle via Windoze CMD or `groovy` command line command).

***However***, I find that if I do a `gradle installDist`, the resulting "distributed" version of the app works OK: responds to each character entered and waits for the next. Thank God for that! But for testing and development purposes it'd be nice if a solution could be found to the problem of trying to run with Gradle.  It seems likely that some tests will fail when they shouldn't as a result of this.

***reply to tkruse***

here's the build.gradle.  DummyMain.groovy is under src\main\groovy\core.

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = "core.DummyMain"

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    api 'org.apache.commons:commons-math3:3.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.guava:guava:21.0'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.6.0-alpha-2'
    compile 'net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.6.11'
    compile 'org.jline:jline:3.7.0'
}
```

The answerer to the only answer (so far) is the author of JLine.  I think it's very unlikely that Gradle uses JLine, and that if that were the case Guillaume Nodet would have mentioned that...

Comment: it would help to show parts of your buildgradle so others can reproduce. Gradle itself might depend on a specific version of jline, so you could end up with 2 versions of jline on the classpath

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you noticed that in one case, you're referring to `jline-terminal-jna` while in the other case you're referring to `jline`.  While the `jline` jar contains the `jline-terminal-jna` jar content, the dependencies are slightly different, because the JNA library is a mandatory dependency of `jline-terminal-jna`, but an optional dependency of `jline`.

You should check the class of the `Terminal` instance created by JLine and verify that this is the expected `JnaWinSysTerminal` class.

It could also be related to a JLine issue raised a while ago, https://github.com/jline/jline3/issues/77.
However, there's nothing to fix in JLine, and the related gradle issue was rejected and closed (see https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/1099).

Comment: Thanks... in fact the "jline-terminal-jna"/"jline" issue turns out to be non-significant, it's just that I was experimenting with both ... have now corrected to dispel confusion.  Re your other point: I get `PosixSysTerminal` with the Groovy script and this same class with the `installDist` distribution (i.e. the ones which work) but ... oh dear, `DumbTerminal` with `gradle run`, `gradle build`, etc.

Comment: Re your final para: this is a bit beyond my paygrade (especially the `ProcessBuilder` stuff) ... but as far as my investigation goes, it appears that the latest version of maven `exec` plugin (1.6.0), 2017-03, does use Java 7. So the question then is whether the latest version of Gradle's `application` plugin uses this 1.6.0., or indeed whether I can configure this Gradle plugin to use a downloaded 1.6.0 version. Have posted on the Gradle forum https://discuss.gradle.org/t/identify-configure-maven-exec-plugin-version-used-by-javaexec/26647 ... I take it you don't use Gradle... !

Comment: It's not only about being able to use java 7, but there is some necessary code changes.  I raised 2 PRs on maven-exec-plugin and graddle, but none of them got through.  Feel free to ping the 2 teams again, I'm willing to help from my side.

Comment: OK, merci de l'info.  J'ai "pingué" Gradle forum... mais sans réponse encore.  Dommage que ce soit si compliqué à faire avec Gradle.